# How to track the remote branch which already exists

Tags: github

I am using git (1.7 version) as my repository .
One of my colleague as created a new branch named `niuver_98` commited his changes  and pushed this branch to github (remote).

I could able to checkout this branch using the following steps

```
git fetch 
git checkout niuver_98
```

This is all working fine .

But when i executed the command

```
git branch
```

Why its not showing the branch niuver_98 ??

My question is that how can i track this branch niuver_98 ??

Please help , thank you very much .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git checkout -b niuver_98 
git pull
```

or

```
git checkout --track origin/niuver_98
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , Are these two commands must be executed after the git fetch  and git checkout (which i mentioned  above)

Comment: the first command means creating a branch niuver_98 (same as your colleague) and switch to it, and second pull the all files from the remote repository. updated the answer.

Comment: I heard that there is command like git track -- for this purpose , but i am not aware of this

Comment: Thank you very much origin/niuver_98(forward slash)  or origin  niuver_98(space) which one is correct ?